# MySQL: Best way to combine multiple MAX() selects with an array?

Tags: mysql, arrays, max

I hope someone could give me a general direction on this problem:

The starting point is an array of ids of db records.

```
array ids = [45,23,14,7];
```

Those records have some columns, i.e.

```
id,price,rating
7,$5.00,5
14,$2.00,4
23,$5.00,2
45,$5.00,5
```

What I would need is

1. the items with max(price) (or something equivalent).
2. if there is more than one item with the same price, get the ones with max(rating) (or something equivalent).
3. Finally, if there is still more than one item, *take the one that comes first in the array.*

I'm particularly stuck with point 3. Is there a way to do that in (My)SQL, or should I do that in code?

Thank you for your reading.

Comment: Hmm, actually if you want the `first in the array` then the array is ordered somehow. So the solution is applying the same ordering criteria in SQL

Comment: Yes, the order of the array is no problem. But I am unsure if the result will keep that order, or how to apply that order once I got a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answer by @jasonlfunk you can add an extra order clause to take into account your array as well:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (45,23,14,7) ORDER BY price DESC, rating DESC, FIELD(id,45,23,14,7) ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You are right, the extra order clause does the trick. Thank you both for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (45,23,14,7) ORDER BY price DESC, rating DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Oh my god, of course! Much simpler than I thought it would be. Thank you a 1000 times!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, had to test first...I was abou tot mark it, but there seems to be a min time limit until acceptance. Anyway, atkaye is correct when adding FIELD() to preserve the array order, so in all fairness I've got to give the acceptance to him :)

Comment: Ah, I missed the last part of the question. Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

...I think about your point 3 ..it must be done in code, the result of mysql not necessarily returns results in the order or the array, if applying order by price, then by rating still returning more than one item your code should be able to receive a list instead a single row, and then make the comparisson in code.